# iOS sandbox independent file path

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am developing a simple app for iOS.
And I was really surprised that when image is written like in the code below, the path stays valid before the app restarts. After the app restarts the new sandbox is created and this invalidates the previous path. I am trying to find a way to have sandbox independent file path. Is it even possible without going through the resolution cycle (i.e. FileManager.default.url...)?

```
    static func saveToDocument(name: String, image: UIImage) -> String? {
    guard let data = image.pngData() else { return nil; }
    guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let file = directory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).png");
        try data.write(to: file!)
        return file?.absoluteString
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of saving the whole path, you can just save the file name. This way by appending the file name to the documents directory you will always get your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop searching, there is no way, and there is a good reason for that: The safety of your data.

You always have to get the URL of the documents directory with `FileManager.default.url(for`, it's not that expensive.

`Guard`ing the URL is not necessary, the documents folder is guaranteed to exist.

Return only the file name rather than the complete URL string and I recommend to make the function `throw` to hand over all errors.

```
enum FileError : Error {
    case noData
}

static func saveToDocument(name: String, image: UIImage) throws -> String {
    guard let data = image.pngData() else { throw FileError.noData }
    let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)            
    let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).png")
    try data.write(to: fileURL)
    return fileURL.lastPathComponent
}
```

And never use `NS...` classes like `NSURL` in Swift if there is a native counterpart (`URL`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please help me understand it better? Externally it is quite clear why sandboxing make sense. No app outside the sandbox can assume the stateful name of let's say Bank of America app. But internally, how is this more secure, if there is still API figure out the exact path?

Comment: Only externally matters.